# How to make crontab housekeep script to remove files older than 60days in a directory in redhat 7

Tags: linux, redhat

I have below directory to housekeep :

/interface/P23/FTP/MTSI/arc

/interface/P23/FTP/iMind360/arc

/interface/P23/FTP/ServiceNow/arc

can anyone help me to show some scripts to remove the files older than`enter code here` 60days?

i want to keep only new files and housekeep the old files inside those directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use find command  as bellow

```
find <Path> -mtime +<NumberOfDay> -exec rm {} \;
```

-mtime, is used to specify the number of days old that the file is.

-exec, allows you to pass in a command such as rm. The {} \; at the end is required to end the command.

Comment: able to use. already put in crontab. thanks all for your support

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, making untested Bash go through isn't my strong suit, but it should be something like this:

```
secs_to_wait=5184000
root_dirs=(
    /interface/P23/FTP/MTSI/arc
    /interface/P23/FTP/iMind360/arc
    /interface/P23/FTP/ServiceNow/arc
)
for root_dir in $root_dirs; do
    for i in $(ls $root_dir); do
       # seconds since last modified
       mod_time=$(stat --format "%X" $i)
       if [ $mod_time -ge $secs_to_wait ]; then
           rm -f $i
       fi
    fi
fi
```

Now, you can run that as a cronjob however often you want. An alternate solution is to use a filesystem monitor like [inotifywait](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to figure out all these gory details for you. All you have to do is figure out how to specify your age requirement as an inotify event, and it'll take care of the rest on a daemon. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader ;)

> Blockquote

Comment: i save your script in houskp.sh file. and i edit make it 5 second to try. But when i run ./houskp.sh below error appear :

Comment: [root@mykultestrhel04t scripts]# ./houskp.sh
-bash: ./houskp.sh: Permission denied

Comment: You need to run chmod +x houskp.sh first. Still, use the other solution listed; it’s more succinct.

Comment: i already fix the permission error, but i got second error as below, please help :

[root@mykultestrhel04t scripts]# ./houskp.sh
./houskp.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./houskp.sh: line 13: `    fi'

Comment: Like I said, don’t use this. Use the other solution that uses “find”.